# How do I return a request's response with a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, request

I have a problem with request's callback !
i want to return for example the body of the request's response but I don't know how to do it...
Please Help me !

```js
const request = require('request');


function doCall(my_url, callback) {
    request({
        url: my_url,
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (err, res, body) {
        return callback(body);
    });
}

body = doCall('https://google.com/', function(res){
    console.log(res); // It works
    return res;
})

console.log(body); // But here I haven't my body from the request

anotherCall(body);
```

Thank you !!!!!

Comment: Yes, I tried it with no success ...

Comment: You. Cannot. Return. The. Value. To. `body`. You simply can't. Put `anotherCall(res)` into the `function (res)` callback.